# Doctrine on query built hook

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Is there a hook in Doctrine \ Symfony to manually edit queries that are built by Doctrine before they are sent to the database?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't... You're not supposed to do that in my opinion.
Maybe using DQL will help you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DQL hooks](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/ru/event-listeners#dql-hooks) and/or [record listeners](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/ru/event-listeners#record-listeners). DQL hooks are probably what you want. Make sure you turn on callbacks!